# Zend Framework normal query to Zend_Db_Table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is my query:

```
"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE MATCH(title, text) AGAINST('".$word."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

How can I do this with Zend_Db_Table, I mean($this->select()...)

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dbTable = new Default_Model_DbTable_Posts();
$select = $dbTable->select()->where('MATCH(title, text) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE', $word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the against:

```
$dbTable = new Default_Model_DbTable_Posts();
$select = $dbTable->select()->where('MATCH(title, text) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $word);
```